# Using Dependency Injection I find myself creating factories to do Unit Testing. Is this normal?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, dependency-injection, mocking

check the following simplified example code:

```
public class RequestManager
{
    public RequestManager()
    {

    }

    public void ProcessRequest(byte[] data)
    {
        IRequest request = new Request(data);
        request.Send();
    }
}
```

When I find myself with this code to be able to test it I end with:

```
public class RequestManager
{
    private IRequestFactory requestFactory;

    public RequestManager(IRequestFactory requestFactory)
    {
        this.requestFactory = requestFactory;
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(byte[] data)
    {
        IRequest request = this.requestFactory.CreateRequest(data);
        request.Send();
    }
}
```

The CreateRequest method just has the new Request(data) so I can mock the factory and return a mock as well.

The thing is that I start to have lots of factories for so simple tasks and I wonder if this is normal or if there is a pattern or another approach that can help me overcome this problem.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only this is normal but also is a sign of decent design. In an application where DI is applied correctly you won't need factories for:

- objects resolved from dependency injection container
- POCO/DTO (as they are simple value stores)
- in most cases, .NET BCL objects (although this may vary)

For everything else, factory is a good choice. Why?

- it provides unified way of object creation (so that entire *team* knows that when you need `IRequest` instance, you should inject `IRequestFactory`)
- it doesn't raise any unnecessary questions (like *"Should I set `SomeProperty` after creation?"* or  *"Which constructor do I use?*. `Factory.CreateInstance()` is trivial and intuitive - no need to explain anything, all the decisions are already made and embedded within factory itself)
- it simplifies unit testing greatly combined with mocking (especially when actual objects can't be created with fake data easily)

Unit testing aside, first two points carry extremely huge benefit when you return to your code in 3, 6, 12 months - factories ***relieve* developers from making decisions** about stuff that shouldn't require any decision to be made in first place.

Instead of wondering *which constructor to use* and *what parameters to pass* you have very simple contract which answers all possible questions and you, as a developer, can focus on actual problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
IRequest request = new Request(data);
```

this line is all the contrary to Dependancy Injection. Its a hardcoded dependancy. This line binds the `RequestManager` class with the `Request` implementation of `IRequest`.

Maybe try this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(IRequest request)
{
   request.Send();
}
```

This way, the `RequestManager` does not have to have any knowledgle of the IRequest implementations. You can hand it a mock object/stub and it wont even feel a thing! OF course, that means that the class creating its `RequestManager` needs to know that dependancy. But hey, you can hand it its `RequestManager` in an analogous way!

In the end, all the dependancies focus in a single point. Usually we use some framework to handle the wiring things together for us, for example basing on an XML file.

The whole point of dependancy incejtion is to provide the needed concrete objects through setters or constructor arguments. Dependancy Injection frameworks allow you to centralise the dependancies in a single place, from where you can easily change concrete classes provided to other classes that need them. That way you can set up using mock objects in tests too - very convinient!

[Here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) you can find an awesome article about Dependancy Injection

Comment: The one calling the ProcessRequest does not know anything about requests as this class is internal to the RequestManager. I know that this is against DI that's why I end using a factory, ergo the question

Comment: @SoMoS Check out the article and see if it clarifies anything. If not, please come back and we will try to make it work :)

Comment: I read this article several times. It's a classic and I'm using constructor injection. I'm just asking if this is normal or not.

Comment: care to join the chat?

Comment: @SoMoS because I cant see why you put a factory in the RequestManagers constructor instead of the IRequest that it actually needs. It could be handled by your DI framework, if I understand correctly.

Comment: The caller of ProcessRequest should indeed not know anything about requests. You should follow the chain all the way up to the Composition Root.